# How can I find the IP of a network service from the iPhone

Tags: iphone, networking, nmap

I want to use some sort of nmap-like functionality to autodiscover a ASP.NET web server (running on port 443) somewhere on the network.  This way users don't have to find and enter the IP manually.  Is there a good/clean way to do this?

Comment: You could have the server advertise its address via Bonjour.

Comment: @ceejayoz: I'm not sure getting an ASP.NET web service to broadcast itself on Bonjour is going to be the easiest thing in the world.

Comment: I'm not sure running nmap on an entire network is a good idea either.

Comment: I'm going to try bonjour... we'll see how that goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @ceejaoz's comment above, I was able to do this pretty easily in Bonjour.

I used [Mono.Zeroconf](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono.Zeroconf), a .NET/Mono Bonjour library, to advertise the service, and the default iOS `NSNetService` stuff to resolve it on the iPhone.  (There's plenty of tutorials on how to do this around the nets).

I made a Windows Service in Visual Studio to actually run the code that advertises the ip and port, since a web service isn't really a good place for that.

One big caveat (as of December 2010): the Bonjour DLLs that come with Mono.Zeroconf are totally broken (no errors, they just don't do anything).  Steal the ones from [Pidgin](http://www.pidgin.im/) instead.